# BeautifulSoup to output extracted text line by line

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

HTML sample below. I am using BeautifulSoup to extract the texts.

```
txt = """[<dd class="qs" id="qsff"><br/>Pretty women wonder where my secret lies. <br/>I'm not cute or built to suit a fashion model's size<br/>But when I start to tell them,<br/>They think I'm telling lies.<br/><br/>I say,<br/>It's in the reach of my arms<br/>The span of my hips,<br/>The stride of my step,<br/>The curl of my lips.<br/><br/></dd>]"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, "lxml")

for node in soup:
    print (node.text)

# [Pretty women wonder where my secret lies. I'm not cute or built to suit a fashion model's sizeBut when I start to tell them,They think I'm telling lies.I say,It's in the reach of my armsThe span of my hips,The stride of my step,The curl of my lips.]
```

It shows me a whole chunk of string as above, but I want to have them line by line, like:

```
Pretty women wonder where my secret lies.
I'm not cute or built to suit a fashion model's size
But when I start to tell them,
....
```

I tried below but it doesn't work.

```
for node in soup.find_all('br'):
    print (node.text)
```

What's the right way to output them line by line?

Comment: `print(soup.dd.get_text(separator='\n'))`

Comment: @PhungDuyPhong, thank you. it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over strings, not nodes:

```
for node in soup.dd.strings:
    print(node)
#Pretty women wonder where my secret lies. 
#I'm not cute or built to suit a fashion model's size
#But when I start to tell them,
#....
```

And why do you enclose your text in square brackets?

Comment: thank you! because it was from a previous extraction. :)